# searchbox with jquery ui

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to get my searchbox to look like that of facebook, where the button looks like it's inside the textbox. Please see the facebook home page.
I am using jquery ui and the graphics with it, for the button, problem is I think it adds borders to the button is creates, hence there is this separation between the text input and the button, anyway to get around this?

Here is my search form

```
<div class="div-search-form" style="display: inline; float: right;"><form method="get" id="search_form" class="" action="/searches">
        <input type="text" value="Search" name="q" id="q" class="search-term" style="border: medium none;">
             <span class="small-button"><a id="search_button" href="#" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Search"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span></a></span>
        </form>
      </div>
```

### UPDATE

I think I am getting there.

Here is  my css

```
.search-button {
    background-position: -160px -112px;
    display: block; text-indent: -99999px; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ff0084_256x240.png);
    float:left;
    border-left: 0 !important;
    background-color: white;
    width:16px;

}
.search-term {
    padding:1px 5px 1px 20px;
    border: 0 !important;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_eeeeee_40x100.png);

}
.search-term:focus{
    background-image: none;
}

.div-search-form {
    margin-right: 0;
    float:right;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

### AND THE markup

```
<div class="div-search-form"><form method="get" id="search_form" class="" action="/searches">
      <input type="text" value="Search" name="q" id="q" class="search-term">

        <a class="search-button" id="search-button" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Notice that unless I put a &nbps; the background image of the anchor tag doesn't show up. wonder why?

Also, Not sure how to make them both the same size and bigger in height. Right now they are both 16px in height, but If I play with the padding the alignment goes out of whack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you need to do is create an image that mirrors the style of the input field on the left.

You will float the input field next to the button.

For the input field on the left control the CSS so there is not a right border, also make sure you add some padding, so that the text doesn't run into the button.

```
input.search-term { float:left; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-right:none; padding:5px; }
```

On your image do not have a left border

```
.smallbutton a { float:left; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-left:none; background:url(../imagepath); disiplay:block; height:XXpx; width:XXpx; }
```

***The trick isn't as much about a technical way to do it, rather being creative with the images and CSS you use to accomplish the goal.***

Comment: No good at images, that's why I was hoping I could use the jquery graphic somehow :). Anyway to swing this within the standard jqueryui? Also, rather not create other images for extra download (even if I was capable!)

Comment: Sure you could do it all with CSS, you just have to be creative with your CSS.  Facebook is using an image sprite for theirs "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zC/r/pluchFZRq3G.png" and then CSS to create the borders.

Comment: Does the image have to be the same height as the input?

Comment: technically no the image could be a background and you could position it so that it looks like it lines up, but if you aren't that familiar with using images/backgrounds that would be the easiest route.